# iOS 8 and mobile Safari (7+): svg events not triggering

Tags: javascript, events, svg, mobile-safari, ios8

With the recent update to iOS8 our webapp working primarily on iPad has become broken.

More specifically the issue happens on SVG and events that should be triggered, and aren't.

We use SVGs as maps, the "g" and "polyfill" markups serving as identifier. This works/ed fine in iOS7 and all desktop browser. As a matter of fact it even works in Safari 8 that comes with iOS8. It is when the "app is added to homescreen" that it becomes broken (Safari version is then 7+ as per platform.version).

Here are the event listeners we are adding to our svg document:

```
var localSvgDoc = emb.getSVGDocument();
localSvgDoc.addEventListener( 'click', app.mapWorldCont.countryPicked, false);
localSvgDoc.addEventListener( 'touchstart', app.mapWorldCont.countryPicked, false);
// prevent elastic scroll on maps
localSvgDoc.addEventListener( 'touchmove', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
```

Worth noting that we render the SVG through an embed, but the issue is the same in an object or an iframe.

If I inspect the element in Safari Console, the events are actually listed in the list of eventListeners.

It just seems there is no way to trigger them (even programmatically with Jquery for instance).

---

Solved-ish: we found a workaround by actually forcing the event listener on each elements' id of the svg:

```
_.each(this.countryBlocks, function(blockName){
    _.each(blockName, function(countryID) {
        localSvgDoc.getElementById(countryID).addEventListener( 'click', app.mapWorldCont.countryPicked, false);
        localSvgDoc.getElementById(countryID).addEventListener( 'touchstart', app.mapWorldCont.countryPicked, false);
    });
});
```

Comment: Maybe this helps to know: No touch events in iframes from home screen app on iOS8 are in fact working. Not one. Only click and other events are triggered. This is a bug.

Comment: Yeah and there seems to be quite a certain amount of them...No video will play either (or haven't found the workaround). It kind of loads but impossible to start...Dirty Safari 7+, bad Apple

Comment: Video and audio tags on home screen are not working.

Comment: Still even under 8.1.1 apple ignores the need to register touch events on iframes in home screen use. I can’t believe this. This will be ignored forever as it seems :-(